# How can i get the list of AID in java card?

Tags: javacard

I want to get All of the AID in a java card .
I do not know what do i?
Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: Could you explaint your question? What is your problem, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

In Global Platform compliant cards and using the gpshell you can use the get_status command with the "-element e0" arguments.

From the man page:
get_status
              -element e0 List applets and packages and security domains

You will probably need to previously select the card manager and create a secure channel (using the select and open_sc commands)

You can check examples for applet listing for different development smart cards on gpshell source code (the list*.txt files)

Comment: Useful answer, but only for persons that have access to the Global Platform key set used for the card, if Global Platform is used at all.